# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2 iso

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, offline

I have downloaded 7.4GB iso file of **Visual Studion 2015 Enterprise Update 2**

`en_visual_studio_enterprise_2015_with_update_2_x86_x64_dvd_8510142.iso`

I need to Install all of its features but can't allow it to download anything during installation due to metered connection.

My Question is: How can I force Visual Studio to install all the available features in the iso file but not to download anything during installation.

I checked available options from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx) but not sure about `/NoRefresh` Option.

[image]

As it states that It stops updates and I need to install Update 2 which is definitely included in the iso file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the /noweb option.

I found it at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw%28v=vs.140%29.aspx#bkmk_offline) link.

Comment: Thanks. I think this would work and I'm not sure how I missed it. Maybe they updated it.